What's the name of this movie?
I watched this movie when I was a child and have no idea what it is called. It was a horror movie from the early 2000s or late 90s. I remember it was a younger woman white or Hispanic married to a larger black man who was dead maybe. Anyway in it she discovers he wasn't who she thought he was. She found tapes of him hurting women in a barn. The movie ends on a cliffhanger of her seeing a woman about to be hit by a car and she suddenly disappears, she realizes she was only a ghost. She didn't know she was psychic. 

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification.  What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Sounds exactly like Gothika as @Ghotir has answered

This sounds very similar to Gothika.

I watched this movie when I was a child and have no idea what it is called. It was a horror movie from the early 2000s or late 90s.

Gothika was released in 2003.

I remember it was a younger woman white or Hispanic married to a larger black man who was dead maybe.

Halle Barry is the lead actress; she is neither white nor Hispanic.  (You could also be thinking of Penélope Cruz, who was a key supporting actress.)  Halle Barry's character was married to a character played by Charles S. Dutton, older than she is, who could be described as a "larger black man".  Much of the movie revolves around the fact that he was murdered (Halle Barry's character is the suspected killer).

Anyway in it she discovers he wasn't who she thought he was. She found tapes of him hurting women in a barn.

Yes and yes (including "in a barn").  "Hurting" also included at least one murder.

The movie ends on a cliffhanger of her seeing a woman about to be hit by a car and she suddenly disappears, she realizes she was only a ghost. She didn't know she was psychic.

The ending has a young boy (played by Noah Bernett) about to be hit by a bus before he disappears.  This plays to the themes of being psychic (and/or crazy).  There is also an iconic scene, much earlier, where a young woman (played by Kathleen Mackey) is about to be hit by a car.  This also ties into the theme of being psychic (and/or crazy).

+1 Without knowing, Halle could be confused for Hispanic as she has a very light tone.
